# Gradle failed to build the app - unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: ssl, gradle, networking, https, corporate-policy

Anyone can suggest me how to add the gradle trust all jar in my existing project. i have added the below information in
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GzUS.png)
But i have received the below error:Caused by:
org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.1/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_propert at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:128) Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
**Please help or suggest how to eradicate the  PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**